# UICollectionView Reloading cells but not deleting old ones

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been trying to implement a collection view in which a user can like a post but for some reason when a user does do that it updates the feed but simply doubles the number of cells and leaves the old cells which should be gone. In short, half the cells are updated and the other half are the old values. Basically I cannot figure out how to simply update the current cells without having a problem. Ideally I would like for the user to press the like button and nothing else to happen besides that button turning to "Unlike" and the number of likes on the post to be changed in the collectionview.

Here is the code for loading the collection view cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = feedCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyGroupFeedCollectionViewCell

    cell.postKey = feedArray[indexPath.row].postKey

    //clears the cells first
    cell.profileImage.image = nil
    cell.usernameLabel.text = nil
    cell.usernameLabel2.text = nil
    cell.groupName.text = nil
    cell.postImageView.image = nil
    cell.postCaptionTextView.text = nil
    cell.timeStamp.text = nil

    //load profile picture
    cell.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: feedArray[indexPath.row].ProfilePic), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"no profile picture.png"))

    //load username
    cell.usernameLabel.text = feedArray[indexPath.row].Username
    cell.usernameLabel2.text = feedArray[indexPath.row].Username

    //load groupName when in home feed
    cell.groupName.text = feedArray[indexPath.row].GroupName

    //load postImage
    cell.postImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: feedArray[indexPath.row].PostImage), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"penguinPanorama"))

    //load caption
    cell.postCaptionTextView.text = feedArray[indexPath.row].caption

    //load likes once likes are implemented
    //checks if the user has liked the post or not
    databaseRef.child("likes").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child(feedArray[indexPath.row].postKey).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if(snapshot.exists())
        {
            cell.liked = "Yes"
            cell.likeButton.setTitle("Unlike", for: .normal)
        }
        else{
            cell.liked = "No"
            cell.likeButton.setTitle("Like", for: .normal)
        }
    })
```

Here is the code for the function in which the like button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func likeButton_tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.likeButton.isEnabled = false
    print(self.postKey)
    print(self.liked)

    //make it so liking or unliking adds or subtracts from the total number of likes on the post
    if liked == "Yes"
    {
         self.databaseRef.child("likes").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child(self.postKey).removeValue()

        let NewLikeNumber = likeNumber - 1
        self.databaseRef.child("GroupPosts").child(self.groupName.text!).child(self.postKey).child("likes").setValue(NewLikeNumber)
        print(NewLikeNumber)
    }
    else{
        self.databaseRef.child("likes").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child(self.postKey).setValue("")

        let NewLikeNumber = likeNumber + 1
        self.databaseRef.child("GroupPosts").child(self.groupName.text!).child(self.postKey).child("likes").setValue(NewLikeNumber)
        print(NewLikeNumber)
    }

    self.likeButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Where are you reloading the collection view?

Comment: @ebby94 I am reloading the collection view at the end of the function in which the posts are loaded. This function is called in viewwillappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the likes, I recommend you using Firebase transactions, as your like count could end up being a mess because of concurrent modifications :

```
 func likePost(_ post: Post, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {

    guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
       return
    }

    databaseRef.child(likes).child(currentUserId).child(postKey).runTransactionBlock ( { (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

              if var data = currentData.value as? [String: Any] {
                  var count = data["likesCount"] as! Int
                  count += 1
                  data["likesCount"] = count
                  currentData.value = data
                  return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
              }

              return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

     }, andCompletionBlock: { (error, success, snapshot) in

                // ...

     })

}
```

And of course the same goes for the user unliking a post.

Now to know whether the user liked the post or not, you could create a boolean in your class to save the like state locally :

```
private var isPostLiked = false
```

And whenever the user tap on the like button, do a simple check like that :

```
     func handleLikeTapped() {

            guard let post = post else {
                return
            }

            if isPostLiked {

                NetworkManager.shared.likePost(post, completion: { [weak self] in

                    // Once the completion handler of your method is called, the likes count in your database is now updated. 
                    // To avoid making another read in the database just now, you can just
                    // Update your count (a label that shows how many likes a specific post received I guess ?) locally here so that the user can see in realtime the change (with animation or not depending on what you want to achieve)

                    // And finally update the like state of the post so that if the user click again on like it wouldn't mess everything up:

                    self?.isPostLiked = false
                })

            }

            else {

                NetworkManager.shared.dislikePost(post, completion: { [weak self] in

                    // ...
                })
            }
   }
```

Now of course later if you need to access the likes count in a different view controller, you would just use `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` to get the updated likesCount from your database.

Just let me know if you have any questions !